# React - can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted (scaledrone app)

Tags: reactjs, state, jsx, setstate, scaledrone

it gives me the same error no matter what i try;
its either that error or my push function breaks

full error is: "Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the App component."

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Messages from "./Messages";
import Input from "./Input";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      messages:[],
      member: {
        username: randomName(),
        color: randomColor(),
      },
    }
    this.drone = new window.Scaledrone("Qk3ma3HbEXr6Lwh7", {
      data: this.state.member
    });
    this.drone.on('open', error => {
      if (error) {
        return console.error(error);
      }
      const member = {...this.state.member};
      member.id = this.drone.clientId;
      this.state.member = {...member};
    });
    const room = this.drone.subscribe("observable-room");
    room.on('data', (data, member) => {
      const mcopy = this.state.messages;
      mcopy.push({member, text: data});
      this.setState({mcopy});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <h1>Chat Aplikacija</h1>
        </div>
        <Messages
          messages={this.state.messages}
          currentMember={this.state.member}
        />
        <Input
          onSendMessage={this.onSendMessage}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onSendMessage = (message) => {
    this.drone.publish({
      room: "observable-room",
      message
    });
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does replacing `this.setState({mcopy});` with `this.setState({messages: mcopy})` work?

Comment: I haven't touched class in React for a while, but maybe you can't set the member state directly like that. Or you could try move the code into ComponentDidMount function

Comment: @TechySharnav unfortunately it does not

Comment: Then try moving the entire code block, after constructor, and before render to `ComponentDidMount()`

Comment: @NanoBit to you too; i haven't noticed the comment because i was spiraling; thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call setState() in the constructor(), Technically setState is meant to update existing state with a new value. you should move state manipulation to ComponentDidMount life cycle.

Also, don't mutate state, instead make a clone and then make changes.

Comment: thank you Qamar, TechySharnav and NanoBit - this was the solution i needed.